# Stopping firefox from submitting form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, firefox

I have problem stopping a button from submitting a form.it does not work in FF but it works fine in IE and chrome. Any advice?

```
function CheckExhibitsAndRunningLog(taskId) {

    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (event.stopPropagation) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    event.returnValue = false;
    //e.cancelBubble = true;        
//  window.event.preventDefault();
    //this is web service call
    Empire.ScriptServices.CheckTaskUpdateValid(taskId, OnComplete, OnError);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Need to know how CheckExhibitsAndRunningLog() is called.

Answer (score 1):

After making some assumptions .....

To suppress conventional (HTML) form submission in response to a button, you can simply put `onsubmit="return false;"` in the form tag, or the javascript equivalent :

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
if(myForm) {
    myForm.onsubmit = function() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

or in jQuery :

```
$("#myForm").on('submit', function() {
    return false;
});
```

With this inhibition in place :

a) `CheckExhibitsAndRunningLog()` should then reduce to :

```
function CheckExhibitsAndRunningLog(taskId) {
    Empire.ScriptServices.CheckTaskUpdateValid(taskId, OnComplete, OnError);
}
```

b) Form submission can still be forced from elsewhere in your javascript with `myform.submit();` if necessary.